# Checkbox click event not firing

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js, webforms

My ASP .Net page has a repeater that is loaded from AJAX. This AJAX page repeater has a column of checkboxes. The repeater is inside a html table.

```xml
<input id="chkOptionSelected" runat="server" enableviewstate="false"
type="checkbox" data-bind="click: Add" />
```

On the main page, I have a label whose value is computed by a JavaScript function. My view model:

```
function VM() {
    var self = this;
    self.totalSqft = ko.observable(TotalSqFt);
    self.Add = function () {
        self.totalSqft(TotalSqFt);
        return true;
    }; 
}
ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

`TotalSqFt` is a global variable. The label is:

```xml
<asp:Label ID="lblTotalSqFt" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" data-bind="text: totalSqft"></asp:Label>
```

The click event computes the new total in a javascript function. All the view model needs to do is update the label with the new value.

What am I doing wrong? Is it because the checkbox is inside of AJAX content? I can see it all in the view source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like @Jeroen said, `asp:Lable` will processed by server and render differently at client side.

so instead you can use normal html `label` and use `runat="server"` if you want to access it at server

check this working demo http://jsfiddle.net/91mek1tk/

Comment: Yes, will try the html label and see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: I realized what my the issue is. The click on the check box raises another event that computes the Total. I will have to attach another event to the check box.

Comment: I changed the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/91mek1tk/7/ Now, self.totalSqft has the right value, but the label is not getting updated. I changed the label to an HTML one. <label ID="lblTotalSqFt" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" data-bind="text: totalSqft"></label> It's not getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

The direct cause of your issue is most likely that `data-bind` on an `asp:Label` is not rendered. You would need to call [`Attributes.Add` or something similar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a9d6h4f.aspx) to add it.

Having said that, you're mixing Webforms and client-side heavy tech like KnockoutJS in a way that will probably negate the advantages you'd get from using KO, or worse cause lots of inconvenient cases like the one you're having now. I suggest either moving away from asp controls to more html-oriented controls (like you did with the first `input` tag), or dropping KO in favor of other, simpler client side technology (which seems more appropriate anyways, since you're currently using KO merely to handle clicks, whereas it excels mostly at two-way data-binding tasks).

Comment: Thank you, Jeroen. I'm doing a lot of client side computing with jQuery and JavaScript. I don't want to make a server side call to update just that one label. Will try and change the server control to html label. Thanks, again.

Answer (score -1):

Try this for your javascript function:

```
function VM() {
    var self = this;
    self.totalSqft = ko.observable("totalSqft");
    self.Add = function () {
        self.totalSqft("totalSqft");
        return true;
    }; 
}
ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you, JAG. I tweaked the demo and got it working. I had val instead of text for my label in one of the lines and hence was not seeing the reflected value. It's working now. Thanks, everyone.

Comment: Please include the actual, full (but minimal) code for your solution *in the answer*, so it may help others with the same problem.